# retrain a saved model in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am a newbie in machine learning and currently working with scikit-learn python library.I want to know if there is a way to add more training data to a already trained neural network.For example,I am loading a trained neural net instance from a pickle file.Now If I get a wrong prediction,I want to add it to my training data.is that possible?

Comment: it' possible with parameter `warm_start=True`